# How to add HTML to div element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="section-inner">
        <p>Something Here...</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('<i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>').insertAfter('.section-inner');
 });
</script>
```

**Above code I tried but it is not working** can anyone please help me out for this issue.

**Thanks**

Comment: Can you explain what *it not working* mean? Also, your are missing `>` for `i`

Comment: As correctly pointed by many, it should be `></i>` or `/>`.

Answer (score 0):

`.insertAfter` works fine with text make sure that you have added

`<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>` to your file.

```js
jQuery('<i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>').insertAfter('.section-inner');
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
    <div class="section-inner">
        <p>Something Here...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Issue is in HTMLString. Its a typo mistake and not missing resource. Please **do not** answer such questions

Answer (score 0):

**Replace** **`<i class="fa fa-arrow-up"`** **To** **`<i class="fa fa-arrow-up"> </i>`**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   
     jQuery('<i class="fa fa-arrow-up"> </i>').insertAfter(".section-inner");
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="section">
    <div class="section-inner">
        <p>Something Here...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A user with your rep should know this is a typographical mistake and its bad to answer such question

Comment: Again I'll iterate *its bad to answer such question*. A comment should be more than enough.

Comment: i explain in my answer in user mistake and how to solve with example then user can understand easy...

Comment: I'm not doubting your intentions. They are correct. So is your point. But this is a simple mistake that will not add much value to portal as very few people would make same typo mistake. Also answering typo question is a bad practice. We are here to help not debug.

Comment: I really apologise for my Typo Mistake in such question
Typo mistake was only here in question in my code I put exact correct code Actually I am trying to add HTML after a <div> Element in a wordpress theme but it didn't worked

Comment: what you get error in wordpress please insert in your questions

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use this simple method to add a div inside target area
$('.target-area').append('<div></div>');

if you want to wrap a pre existing elemnt to a tag you should use this one

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").wrap("<div></div>");
    });
});
```

Comment: Issue is in the html string and not in OP's code. This is just a typo mistake and we should not answer such questions

Answer (score 0):

.insertAfter works fine how you have used it, but it is not working for you then try as follow

```html
jQuery('.section').append('<i class="fa fa-arrow-up">Appended</i>');
```

JSFiddle you can check here - https://jsfiddle.net/181j7656/